# Lex - recognizing operators as tokens

Tags: c, lex

I am working on learning lex and the turtle language
I am having problems getting lex to recognize operators as tokens + , < , =

I have them stored in a file
I have tried doing it this way

```
\+ or "+" or '+' or [+]
```

I don't get any errors using single quotes but it doesnt match it either or would i need to do that in the file?.

Here is my file

```
fd 3x00
bk
setc 100
int xy3 fd 10 rt 90
rt
lt
setxy
setx
sety
home
seth
pd
pu
ht
st
color
xcor
ycor
heading
random
:=
+
<
```

and here is the program

```
%{

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
int number;

%}
%%

fd                    {printf("Keyword %s\n", yytext);}
[^\t\n\r]             {}
[0-9]+[a-z]+[0-9]+   {printf("Illegal: 3x00\n");}
[\r\t\n]+               {}
bk                    {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
setc                  {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
[0-9]+               {printf("Number: %s\n", yytext);}

int                   {printf(" Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
xy3                   {printf("ID: %s\n", yytext);}
fd[0-9]+              {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);
                  printf("Number %s\n", yytext);}
rt                    {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
lt                    {printf("Keyword: %s\n",yytext);}
setxy                 {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
setx                  {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
sety                  {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
home                  {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
seth                  {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
pd                    {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
pu                    {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
ht                    {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
st                    {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
color                 {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
xcor                  {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
ycor                  {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
heading               {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
random                {printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
:=                    {printf("Keyword: =\n"  );}
\+                    {printf("Keyword: + \n" );}
\<                     {printf("Keyword: < \n");}
%%

main( int argc,char** argv)

{
    if(argc > 1)
    {

        FILE *file;
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(!file)
        {
           fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s \n", argv[1]);
           exit(1);
           }

           yyin = file;

           }

           yylex();

}
```

Error i get is Warning, rule cannot be matched.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Which rule is it saying can't be matched?

Comment: the line where i am using the \+  i also just tried a DOT to match everything else and i get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem

```
[^\t\n\r]             {}
...
[\r\t\n]+               {}
...
\+                    {printf("Keyword: + \n" );}
\<                     {printf("Keyword: < \n");}
```

The `+` and `<` characters will match both the top rule (`[^\t\n\r]`) and the `\+`/`\<` rule. Since they are the same length, the lexer will take the first match, `[^\t\n\r]`, so it will do nothing (`{}`) and it can never match the `\+`/`\<` rule, as it says.  Take the `[^\t\n\r]` rule out and replace it with `.    {}` at the very end of the token list.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!! It works now. The . catches everything else and i also got the add operator matched AWESOME kevin. thank you again..you kick ass =)